# Hive extract numeric value from a string

Tags: regex, string, hive, hiveql, numeric

I have a table as:

```
column1                         column2 
The first value is 200 gb        need to restart (2 times)
The 2nd value is 700 gb          need (optional) to restart (10 times)
```

I am trying to get the numeric values from the table. The expected output is

```
column1_numeric      column2_numeric 
200                   2
700                   10
```

For column1: i trying to get data using: `regexp_replace(column1, '[^0-9]', '') as column1_numeric;`
but this is not working for the 2nd row and returns 2700

For column2: I am trying as: `regexp_replace(regexp_extract(column2,'\\((.*?)\\)'), '[^0-9]', '') as column2_numeric` 
but this is also not working for 2nd row and returns null values

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract last numeric value from the string `'(\\d+)([^0-9]*)$'`:

```
select 
      regexp_extract(column1,'(\\d+)([^0-9]*)$',1) as column1_numeric,
      regexp_extract(column2,'(\\d+)([^0-9]*)$',1) as column2_numeric
   ...
```

It extracts

```
column1_numeric      column2_numeric 
200                   2
700                   10
```

Also instead of `[^0-9]` (not a digit) you can use `\\D`, which is a bit shorter:

```
'(\\d+)(\\D*)$'
```

Comment: It worked! If we have a record as `need (optional) to restart (10 times) for next 3 days` in column 2; how to get the value 10 from it? 
The query now returns 3 for this situation.

Comment: Plus if there is comma in that value (for example: `need (optional) to restart (1,000 times) for next 3 days` -how to avoid comma and get 1000 from it?

Comment: @Tanvir select regexp_extract('need (optional) to restart (1,000 times) for next 3 days','([0-9,]+)',1)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the below regex it will work for both the columns and extract only the number from the string.

```
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
'The first value is 200 gb'.match( numberPattern ).join('') // 200

'need to restart (2 times)'.match( numberPattern ).join('') // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
select REGEXP_REPLACE('The first value is 200 gb','[^0-9]','')
I got result as 200
**Try this :**
select REGEXP_REPLACE(substring('The 2nd value is 200 gb',-6),'[^0-9]','')